# Return only capturing groups (Or any other lookback hack)

Tags: regex, vba

So I'm dealing with fairly complex regular expressions in VBA. Horray for me. Lookbehind isn't supported AT ALL in VBA. Fine.

One potential hack is to say "The string starts at position X", and truncate the string to only search the first portion. I'd prefer not to go this route, but I will if I have to.

Something that seems very promising is capturing groups.

Is there any way to return just the capture group from a regular expression?

**Code:**

```
Function regex(strInput As String, matchPattern As String, Optional ByVal outputPattern As String = "$0") As Variant
    Dim inputRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, outputRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, outReplaceRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim inputMatches As Object, replaceMatches As Object, replaceMatch As Object
    Dim replaceNumber As Integer

    strInput = Replace(strInput, Chr(160), " ")
    
    With inputRegexObj
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = matchPattern
    End With
    With outputRegexObj
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\$(\d+)"
    End With
    With outReplaceRegexObj
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
    End With

    Set inputMatches = inputRegexObj.Execute(strInput)
    If inputMatches.Count = 0 Then
        regex = ""
    Else
        Set replaceMatches = outputRegexObj.Execute(outputPattern)
        For Each replaceMatch In replaceMatches
            replaceNumber = replaceMatch.SubMatches(0)
            outReplaceRegexObj.Pattern = "\$" & replaceNumber

            If replaceNumber = 0 Then
                outputPattern = outReplaceRegexObj.Replace(outputPattern, inputMatches(0).Value)
            Else
                If replaceNumber > inputMatches(0).SubMatches.Count Then
                    'regex = "A to high $ tag found. Largest allowed is $" & inputMatches(0).SubMatches.Count & "."
                    regex = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    outputPattern = outReplaceRegexObj.Replace(outputPattern, inputMatches(0).SubMatches(replaceNumber - 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next
        regex = outputPattern
    End If
End Function
```

**Simple Sample:**

```
Regex("ABC123","ABC(123)")
```

- Currently returns: "ABC123"
- Desired return: "123"

**Complex Sample/desired result:**

- String: ABC 33-99 AA 100-00

  A negative lookforward might be able to work here.
- Strings: 123//45 ; 123//; 123

  I'd like to be able to get 123 in one place, and 45 in another. But how could a negative lookforward work on the 45 when I need to look backwards to establish prior numbers behind?

Comment: You're already using capturing groups (`SubMatches` in VBA), what's wrong with that? "ABC(123)" will return only "123" in `SubMatches(0)`.

Comment: It looks like I needed to add the last optional item, and it all works

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it's fairly simple, and in the code itself- simply use the last optional item, $!, and it grabs the first capture group. $2 for the second, etc.

So instead of Regex("ABC123","ABC(123)"), I need Regex("ABC123","ABC(123)","$1").

Additionally, this lets me use pseudo-lookbacks in VBA, which normally aren't allowed!

Comment: *Aren't allowed*? May be just doesn't exist?